# Is soapUI capable of sending rest requests as html forms?

Tags: rest, soapui, forms

I have created REST service "binding" inside soapUI project from WADL. Currently it sends xmls to servers. Also it is possible for my REST service to send requests as html forms, like in this sample:

```
<FORM action="http://somesite.com/prog/adduser" method="post">
<P>
<LABEL for="firstname">First name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><BR>
<LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="lastname"><BR>
<LABEL for="email">email: </LABEL>
          <INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
</P>
```

Can soapUI automatically generate/simulate such forms from my WADL generated service which I already included to my soapUI project? If not, then how such form requests can be tested with soapUI?

My knowledge of REST is pretty bad, so if my question doesn't make any sense, please point me in right direction and I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer in official [soapUI docs](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html):

> If you are simulating HTML Form submits, you might want to them to use the POST method instead. If we create a corresponding REST Method using the POST (or PUT) verb you will get an option to post query-parameters in the body instead:

[image]